# How to find lower bound of f(n) for master theorem

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relation, lower-bounds, master-theorem

I'm studying the master method to solving a recurrence. It describes three cases, the last one of which depends on what lower bound a function `f(n)` has.

I usually find out the upper bound of a function from its highest term exponent. How would I figure out its lower bound `Ω`?

Comment: I think it is too broad. Roughly speaking, its highest term is also the lower bound of the function in the sense of $\Omega$.

Comment: For every function $f(n)$ it holds that $f(n) = \Omega(f(n))$, and this is a tight lower bound.

Comment: Sorry if it's a broad question. I am learning about asymptotic analysis and don't have a lot of experience. The method asks for the bound but I'm not sure how it is usually found, when applying the method.

Comment: The highest order term is not only big O but also big $\Omega$ (and big $\Theta$).

Comment: Thanks @YuvalFilmus that's interesting. So if I take a look at the exponent of the higher term that can tell me all of them? The upper and lower bounds are defined by constants `c` that multiply a function `g()` that determines the complexity. Is the function always the same and different constants will give us the lower and upper bounds?... Thanks...

Comment: I think your first step should be to look at the definition of $\Omega$. It is symmetric to $O$; the techniques you've learned for $O$ apply with small adaptions.

Comment: Thanks @Raphael. I've read the definition of Ω, but I think that I didn't comprehend it fully. I think that for what I read in your answers Ω uses the same complexity function than O. ...?

Comment: @Emigre  No, not necessarily. I was assuming you understood the definition of $O$.

Comment: @Raphael to a certain extent, I think that I'm in the process of understanding both properly, so apologies again if I don't make sense. I have read their definition. If I had this function for example`f(n) = 2x^2 - 2`, it would imply Θ(n^2), Ω(n^2) and O(n^2), I think. Reading one of the previous answers I thought that that kind of relation would always going to be the case.

Comment: For polynomials it's that easy, yes.

Comment: @Raphael ah I see.Yes, I don't know how to solve that case  -- a non-polynomial.